# Is it possible to have an equality constraint in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, check-constraints

I have the following:

```
create table dbo.Users
(
  Id int identity not null 
    constraint PK_Users_Id primary key clustered (Id),  
  Email nvarchar (120) not null
    constraint UQ_Users_Email unique (Email),
  Username nvarchar (120) not null
    constraint UQ_Users_Username unique (Username)
);
```

Can I set a constraint to make Email and Username **equal**?

Thank You,
Miguel

Comment: Wouldn't it be specifying your DB you have a useless column?

Comment: just make a view that reads the column twice.  makes as much sense.

Comment: Guys...I just don't see any correct situation where a table would have to duplicate information in such way...

Comment: I am using this because in some projects the email is used as username ... so to avoid changing everything in my application i just make both columns equal ... i just add a constraint. does this make sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is the appropriate SQL to address the question directly:

```
create table dbo.Users
(
  Id int identity not null 
    constraint PK_Users_Id primary key clustered (Id),  
  Email nvarchar (120) not null
    constraint UQ_Users_Email unique (Email),
  Username nvarchar (120) not null
    constraint UQ_Users_Username unique (Username)      
);


alter table dbo.Users add constraint CK_EmailEqualsUsername
check (username = email)
```

*A, most likely better, more common approach would be to perform the comparison somewhere higher in the call stack (different layer e.g.: Presentation Layer/Domain Layer/Service Layer)*

Comment: This is a perfectly valid answer - the OP wants a solution that doesn't require reengineering the app. A `CHECK` constraint is a good solution that is transparent to the application code.

Comment: I do the checking on my service layer ... but just in case I have that optional check in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
alter table dbo.Users
add constraint ck_us check(Email=Username)
```